# What are some 3rd party UI components for .NET MVC 2?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, uicomponents

I'm looking for a 3rd party UI component library to be used in .NET 4.0 C# MVC2 web application.

When I google it, **Telerik** comes up all over the first google page.  To be honest, I actually do like it a lot.  So, I'm just wondering what are other alternatives out there?  What are some drawbacks/problems that people have experienced with Telerik?

Also, I've looked at Infragistics and Component Art and here is why they're out of my picture:

**Infgragistics:**  No MVC support (period)

**Component Art:**  Every single component is made with <table> element.  Even something as simple as a dropdown box.  I mean, a UI-expert company should know better than this.

Comment: I reviewed MVCContrib.  There is a lack of documentation there comparing to Telerik.  Given that we have a team of developers who will be using these controls, I would feel more safe sticking with Telerik.

Comment: Makes me sad seeing a Q like this.... correct me if i'm wrong, but apart from being "testable" the other main function of MVC is the ability to have control over the output, why would you now want to relinquish that control by implementing a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Dusty Roberts - Not everyone is a front-end expert.  Sometimes we have to take into consideration a team as oppose to an individual.

Comment: sorry if it came out strong... that was not my intention.

Comment: @Dusty Roberts - Oh, no hard feelings ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) seems like one people use, though i've never had much reason to stray from the telerik mvc controls.

Comment: I don't think I'll be getting anymore answers here.  Thank you for suggestion!

Comment: @Dimskiy, no problem.  i'd stick with telerik unless there's something they're not accomplishing for you, and even then, its open source, so you can change/add functionality at will